# Is there a faster algorithm for chinese postman problem on a unweighted graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given a undirected graph $G=(V,E)$,find a shortest circuit(it ends at the same point it starts) which through every edges at least once.As we all know,we can easily solve it with Edmond's algorithm which has a complexity of $O(|V|^3)$
If we assume that the weight of each edge is 1,and $|V|=O(|E|)$,is there a fast way to get the answer?

Comment: I doubt it. If there were, you could build unweighted graphs that rationally approximate a weighted one with long chains for edges.

Comment: @Thumbnail But long chain means the number of vertices and edges would be very large.

Comment: Yes, but the complexity of the algorithm, assuming it was using some divide-and-conquer or dynamic-programming technique, would not increase substantially.

Comment: @Thumbnail I don't get your point.

Comment: @Thumbnail. For example, the shortest path problem has solutions of different complexity in unweighted and weighted graph.

Comment: You're rigtht. I'm wrong. Though the difference is not enormous: $O(E + V)$ and $O(E + V log V)$, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Directed_graphs_with_nonnegative_weights).